# Pattern - Conditionally replace literals from string using Java

Tags: java, string

How to conditionally replace literals from a string without using multiple String replacements.

```
String string = "{\"body\": \"{\"id\": 45123}\"}";
StringUtils.replace(string, "\"{", "{");
StringUtils.replace(string, "}\"", "}");
```

The code does a basic cleansing of malformed JSON. Can patterns make this multi-step string replacement with a pattern based conditional replacement in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string.replaceAll( "\"(\\{)|(\\})\"", "$1$2" )
```

Comment: Or if you don't want to worry about subsequences... `string.replaceAll( "\"(?=\\{)|(?<=\\})\"", "" ));`